# A package manager for web assets

Tags: javascript, assets, package-managers, asset-management

Do you know a package manager for web assets?

I'd like something that can download libraries such as jQuery so I can plug them into my asset pipeline. The [js.*](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=js+fanstatic&submit=search) python packages for [fanstatic](http://fanstatic.org/) are close, but they pick a single "latest" version of the library, which can lag a few releases behind.

Google's [js cdn](https://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html) has the metadata for a few of them, but is mostly designed to be downloaded by the browser directly.

Answer (score 16):

I've found these package managers for in-browser javascript:

- [CPM](https://github.com/kriszyp/cpm) (CommonJS package manager), focused on Dojo packages, with an archive at http://packages.dojofoundation.org/ (about 60 packages). CPM augments the CommonJS format with a [mappings field](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Packages/Mappings/C) to describe how modules from dependent packages can be require()d
- Caolan's [Jam](http://jamjs.org/), whose archive is at http://jamjs.org/packages/. Here is the [Jam packaging guide](http://jamjs.org/docs#Developing_packages).
- [Ender](http://enderjs.com/) piggybacks on [npm](http://npmjs.org/) for package management, and provides a client that looks like AMD (I'm not sure about AMD compatibility, which according to a bug report is left up to each package). Here are the Ender [packaging docs](http://enderjs.com/#publishing). Here are [packages with the ender keyword](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/ender). Ender doesn't focus on packaging existing libraries, though its Jeesh starter pack is a modular, mostly-compatible replacement for jQuery.

Most of these can publish in the [AMD format](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD) for browser loaders, and can be loaded by [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/). They also tend to use the [CommonJS package format](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Packages) (also used by npm) for their package.json metadata.

I also found [XStatic](http://readthedocs.org/docs/xstatic/), which seems to be a less-active version of fanstatic, and like fanstatic wraps the libraries in Python packages. It has the same limitation (versions tend to lag), but writing a wrapper package seems simple enough that I can bake my own updates.

BPM and fanstatic are aware of non-js assets and can merge or minify CSS.

Comment: I'd like to add [Jam](http://groundcomputing.co.uk/code/jam) as the latest addition to your list of JavaScript package managers.

Comment: [Yeoman](http://addyosmani.com/blog/improved-developer-tooling-and-yeoman/) (yet to be released) also promises some package management in the form of bower (which apparently is by Twitter people and was very briefly availble on npm)

Comment: Jam is IMO the best as it's respecting a requirejs compatible configuration and can easily be set up with a json file similar to the PHP package manager composer.

Answer (score 14):

[Bower](http://bower.io/), the package manager, from Twitter.

> Bower is a package manager for the web. Bower lets you easily install
>   assets such as images, CSS and JavaScript, and manages dependencies
>   for you.
>
> Bower does package management and package management only.

Bower requires [Node](http://nodejs.org) and [npm](http://npmjs.org) (and possibly git for some bower packages). It is also included in [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/), a set of tools to help developers build modern web apps.

Comment: Bower is awesome.  It's the npm of the client side (with fewer packages though).

Comment: -1 bower doesn't support commits and the devs don't seem to want to support it—say goodbye to 90% of the web that isn't the perfect snowflake bower wants it to be =/ they do more then happily support getting the last unstable changes though

Comment: To add to srcspider's comment, in many cases bower is equivalent to doing `git clone` and `git checkout tagname` of the dependency. If the target requires anything more than this and doesn't have a bower config file in its repo it won't work. If the project requires a build process (eg Sinon) it won't work. If you want to use a specific branch or commit instead of a tag it won't work.

Comment: @GusDeCooL, what's wrong with nodejs? It answers the posted question just fine.

Comment: @Gan, Hi, sorry my bad. I tested bower. It seems only use nodejs for some of it library, but our downloaded front-end script can still work fine without nodejs. i already upvoted your answer :)

Answer (score 5):

If you are on Visual Studio 2010, NuGet is best

http://nuget.org/

Answer (score 3):

The author of RequireJS has also created a package / dependency manager called [Volo](https://github.com/volojs/volo):

> Create browser-based, front-end projects from project templates, and
>   add dependencies by fetching them from GitHub. Once your project is
>   set up, automate common tasks.
>
> volo is dependency manager and project creation tool that favors
>   GitHub for the package repository.
>
> At its heart, volo is a generic command runner -- you can create new
>   commands for volo, and you can use commands others have created.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [npm](http://npmjs.org).  It has tons of browser modules in it already, and is way larger than the other options:

http://www.modulecounts.com/