# Managing third party libraries (not node modules) with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, dependencies

I'm using `package.json` file to define nodejs requirements, along with `npm update`, and of course is working fine.

How can I manage (update the easy way) other third party libraries with node? For example:

```
https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone.git
https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap.git
```

In `vendor` folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Summary:** I think you want to use http://twitter.github.com/bower/

**Details:**
There are two ways to understand your question:

- how to manage/update non-`npm` code?
- how to manage/update client-side javascript assets?

The question is worded as the former, but from your included examples I think what you want to ask the latter.

In case of **server-side code**, just insist all code gets shipped with `npm`-style `package.json` manifest. If the author of the code is unresponsive, fork it and add the manifest. There is no excuse.

For **client-side code**, the situation is different. There is **no established standard** for package management, however it's a widely recognized problem and very active field of development. Several challengers have risen recently, trying to grab the dominant position: [BPM](http://getbpm.org), [Jam](http://jamjs.org/) or [Ender](http://ender.no.de/). It's your call which to pick, they are well summarized here: [A package manager for web assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346716/a-package-manager-for-web-assets)

However, all of the above address a slightly **too ambitious problem** - they try to sort out the transport of those modules to the browser (via lazy loading, require-js style, dependency resolution, concatenation/minification etc.) This also makes them more difficult to use.

A new entrant to the field is [Bower](http://twitter.github.com/bower/) from Twitter. It focuses **just** on download/update lifecycle in your `vendor` folder and ignores the browser delivery. I like that approach. You should check it out.

Comment: Bower seems the best way to manage client assets! Thanks for pointing me to it!

Comment: How am I supposed to use things like bootstrap with bower? There's no .css, just .less, and .js is split into lots of different files.

Answer (score 2):

You could go for git submodules:

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

[Using someone else's repo as a Git Submodule on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252450/using-someone-elses-repo-as-a-git-submodule-on-github)

[**UPDATE 1**]
Do this at the root of your repository:

```
git submodule add git://github.com/documentcloud/backbone.git vendors/backbone
git submodule add git://github.com/twitter/bootstrap.git vendors/bootstrap
```

Check this for more: http://skyl.org/log/post/skyl/2009/11/nested-git-repositories-with-github-using-submodule-in-three-minutes/

Answer (score 1):

Although this may not be the nodejs way, and some purists may complain, [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/download/) will do what you want. Even though Composer is used with PHP projects there is no reason why it cannot be used to manage 3rd party **non-npm** repos for nodejs projects too. Obviously it is preferable for the 3rd party library to include a package.json but thats not aways going to happen. I tried this on my current nodejs app and it worked perfectly for me.

Pros:

- One json file specifies custom external dependancies that do not have package.json files
- Customize where packages are stored in the project folder
- Works with private repos and repos not originally intended for use with nodejs

Cons:

- Requires php cli
- An extra step for updating dependancies
- An extra json file for dependancies

Here how to do it (You need to be able to run php from the cli):

**1. Download Composer** (directly into your root nodejs project folder)

```
curl -s https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar > composer.phar
```

**2. Create a composer.json file** (in the root of the project)

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "twitter/bootstrap",
                "version": "2.0.0",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/zipball/master",
                    "type": "zip"
                },
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "master"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "twitter/bootstrap": "2.0.0"
    }
}
```

**3. Run the Composer update**

```
php composer.phar update
```

This will download the package into the `vendor` folder as you requested:

```
├── vendor
│   ├── ...
│   ├── composer
│   │   └── installed.json
│   └── twitter
│       └── bootstrap
│           ├── LICENSE
│           ├── Makefile
│           ├── README.md
│           ├── docs
│           │   ├── assets
│           │   └── ...
│           ├── img
│           │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-white.png
│           │   └── glyphicons-halflings.png
│           ├── js
│           │   ├── bootstrap-affix.js
│           │   └── ...
│           ├── less
│           │   ├── accordion.less
│           │   └── ...
│           └── ...
```

Comment: This sounds good, but I already have `composer.json` file in the root of my project and it's used to manage node js dependencies (express, sequelize, etc...).

Comment: Wait do you mean `package.json`? This would be an additional composer.json file.