# Library manager for Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

Is there a library manager for Sublime Text 2? I'm looking for something similar to [NuGet](http://nuget.org/) where I can, for example, load all files for [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) into my current project in a few, quick steps.

I found [NetTuts fetch](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/introducing-nettuts-fetch/), which is nice, but not very efficient. If I wanted to load dev and prod versions of Bootstrap, I would have to create multiple files and fetch into each of them. Instead, I would like to run a single command to load all of the files into my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [Bower](http://bower.io/). Here is the [plugin](https://github.com/benschwarz/sublime-bower) for Sublime Text 2.

Similar question: [A package manager for web assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346716/a-package-manager-for-web-assets)